# Command line arguments in shell script

Tags: shell, command-line-arguments

Following is the shell script which iterates over command line arguments and prints the values

```
for var in "$@"
do
    echo $var
done
```

Now if i want to iterate from the second command line argument (the first argument being used for some other purpose), what is the command to exclude the first argument alone in iteration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shift`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shift
for var in "$@"; do
    echo "$var"
done
```

Comment: I am trying to initialise an array in shell script like this testArr=( "A" "B" ). But I get the following error ' shell1.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected'. Can you please tell me what the reason for this error is?

Comment: Do you have spaces somewhere? Anyway, please open a new question.

Comment: in "$@" is useless since it's the default. You can just use: for var; do echo "$var"; done

Answer (score 1):

The first argument is in `$1`, so doing

```
var1=$1
```

will store it into `var1`

You can then use `shift` to "delete" the first arg and still use your for loop:

```
~$cat s.sh
var1=$1
shift
echo var1=$var1
for var in "$@"
do
    echo $var
done
~$ ./s.sh 1 2 3
var1=1
2
3
```

From `man bash`:

> shift [n]
>
> The positional parameters from n+1 ... are renamed to $1 ....  Parameters 
>   represented by the numbers $# down to $#-n+1 are unset.  n
>   must be a non-negative number less than or equal to $#.   If  n
>          is  0,  no  parameters  are changed.  If n is not given, it is assumed to be 1.  If n is greater than $#, the positional parameters
>   are not changed.  The return status is greater than zero if n is
>          greater than $# or less than zero; otherwise 0.

Comment: I am trying to initialise an array in shell script like this testArr=( "A" "B" ). But I get the following error ' shell1.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected'. Can you please tell me what the reason for this error is?

Comment: That's a different question. Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486879/how-to-initiate-array-element-to-0-in-bash?lq=1 or http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html ?

Comment: fredtantini: Those seem to be different questions. I am find able to find the reason for the error in initialising array

Answer (score 0):

This example behaves more like a standard unix command line utility. Options are processed in any order and can have modifiers. It does not work for every situation (like modifiers with spaces in them), but I've found it to be very useful for scripts that I want to have some default behavior, but occasionally I want to modify one or more parameters.

```
#!/bin/bash

#defaults
VAR1="Yours"
VAR2="Mine"
VAR3="Ours"
SHARENICE="false"

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
        #single parameter
        -s)  SHARENICE="true"
        shift
        ;;
        #modified parameters
        -1)  VAR1="$2"
        shift 2
        ;;
        -2)  VAR2="$2"
        shift 2
        ;;
        -3)  VAR3="$2"
        shift 2
        ;;
        #you could put a 'usage' function here,
        #or if your last parameter has no modifier,
        #like a mandatory input, it will now be at
        #$1
        *)
        break
        ;;
    esac
done

echo -n "$VAR1, $VAR2 and $VAR3.  "
if [ "$SHARENICE" != "true" ]; then
    echo "Too bad we don't get along."
else
    echo "Good thing we play nice!"
fi
```